# Is Knockout a slow framework?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to convert my ASP.NET MVC application to one using knockout.

After converting my first view i noticed that knockout is taking longer time to render same amount of data as MVC. Here is my knockout code to display list names.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../Assets/knockout/js/knockout-3.0.0.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: lists, visible: lists().length > 0">
        <li>
            <strong data-bind="text: title" ></strong>              
        </li> 
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function List(data) {
            this.title = ko.observable(data.Title);
        }

        function ListViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.lists = ko.observableArray([]);

            $.getJSON("/home", function (json) {
                var data = JSON.parse(json);
                var mappedlists = $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return new List(item);
                });
                self.lists(mappedlists);
            });
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ListViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
```

I am sure knockout cant be that slow, is there something i am missing here

Note: For comparison, I have used both on the same view (side by side) to see which appears first

Comment: In the first case the page arrives formatted. In the second the content is downloaded and formatting starts after the page has loaded, therefore it must be slower.

Comment: @Emil thanks, it was wrong from my part to check the performance on the same page. even if knockout is faster it will render later.

Answer (score 2):

It's slower because of additional call (and page load) for your page.

I suggest to get rid of `getJSON` call and inject your model while rendering the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // our model data

    var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model));

    // start knockout

    MyEntity.Init(data);
</script>
```

Comment: you may need to "install-package Newtonsoft.Json"

Answer (score 2):

In this simple case it makes no sense to use knockout, because you are not benefiting from two-way data binding. All you do is just displaying some data. You can render this data from server side using Razor if you are using ASP.NET MVC. It makes sense to use knockout, then you want to make interactive screens. Also you can use a framework like [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) to build enterprise level Single Page Applications. It uses knockout for data-binding and, in my opinion, it provides real performance advantages to standard ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: the code i shared is one i am using to check the performance of knockout vs mvc. the full application itself is a lob application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the performance between knockout and ASP.NET MVC. One is a client-side framework and the other one is server side.

They both run in complete different environments so a comparison is useless to start with.

Furthermore I wouldn't call running two pages side by side to see which one appears first a decent performance metric.

Comment: these are two of many ways for making a web lob application and performance is a criteria to help one decide. so i wont call it useless. Although i do agree that running side by side is the not the way to compare performance.

Comment: While you can certainly test whether a particular page renders faster using MVC or Knockout, what you're asking for is a comparison of the speed between MVC and Knockout. That is simply not possible, because they do very different things

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this by sending data directly to the view from the controller. This helps you to avoid unwanted ajax calls back to the server. Here is the example:

In controller Method:

```
return View(<viewmodel class name>);
```

and then in view you can use this before applying knockout binding:

```
var jsonData = new HtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.Model));
```

and then could pass this object in knockout viewmodel.